# Program output for Channeling in C

Tags: c, memory

I have written a following piece of code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(i=a;i<b;i++)

void DeclareAndInitArray();
void PrintArray();

int main(){
    DeclareAndInitArray();
    //printf("hello\n");
    PrintArray();
    return 0;
}

void DeclareAndInitArray(){
    int array[100];
    int i;
    FOR(i,0,100){
        array[i]=i;
    }
}

void PrintArray(){
    int array[100];
    int i;
    FOR(i,0,100){
        printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be starting from 0 and then going till 99 but what I am getting is this:

[image]

Can somebody please tell me what are these two values at the beginning and why are they coming?

Comment: For the record, it is a really bad idea to re-invent the C language! Don't write your own obscure version of for loops, there is never a reason to do so and it only makes your code _less_ readable.

Comment: Also, here is an example of where your obscure loop macro will fail miserably: `FOR(i, 0, var & mask)`. If you insist on using function-like macros, which is also a very bad idea, you need to learn how to use them in a safe manner.

Comment: Actually this code can help when you are writing a `sound card driver` and you have to execute little snippets of code with each `hardware interrupt`. So, sometimes we have a lot to do even in one heartbeat that you are not sure that you have time to do it. So, you would have to move ahead of time and put the data required in the space, so that the next time you can directly access it without having to generate it.

Comment: @Lundin For your kind information I didn't say that this particular code will be used for making drivers. I said that `Channeling` may be used for making drivers. I have a good idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: No you don't, if your idea of a good driver is to store 100 bytes on the stack each time you get a hardware interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

`DeclareAndInitArray()` and `PrintArray()` are each using their own separate array. You're declaring it separately in each function:

```
int array[100];
```

So the array you're using in `PrintArray()` has not been initialised, and contains garbage.

You need to declare the array once, and then pass it into `PrintArray()` as a parameter. Try this instead:

```
int main(){
    int array[100];
    DeclareAndInitArray(array);
    //printf("hello\n");
    PrintArray(array);
    return 0;
}

void InitArray(int array[]){
    int i;
    FOR(i,0,100){
        array[i]=i;
    }
}

void PrintArray(int array[]){
    int i;
    FOR(i,0,100){
        printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you see according to the memory allocation and stack pointers then it should be printing the same values because the stack pointer returns to the location of array beginning when DeclareAndInitArray() is returned and PrintArray() is called.

Comment: interestingly, his code works as expected on my machine (64 bit archlinux gcc) (prints all numbers from 0 to 99), any ideas why it does that?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal that is an assumption about the compiler's underlying behaviour which may work, by luck, sometimes. But in many cases it is simply wrong.

Comment: @GrahamBorland I know this is **a** solution but I want the logic behind why my code is not running fine? I would request you to please have a look at the assembly code for this program where it reaches the start of array after DeclareAndInitArray and nothing has been changed so far.

Comment: It is not running because you are relying on undefined behaviour! It will behave differently on every different platform, or with every different compiler. Relying on anything being preserved on the stack beyond the current stack pointer, across multiple function calls, is just broken.

Comment: There is no reason why you would ever use the stack like that. You would allocate the array as a static variable, at file scope. You mentioned hardware interrupts. What do you think happens if a hardware interrupt occurs between the accessing of two of those functions? Or a context switch to another thread, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The two functions you are calling from `main()` have their own copy of array named `array`.

As a results initializations made by function `DeclareAndInitArray()` are not visible in the other function.

To fix this you can:

1) Make the declaration of the array global so that both the function have access to the same array.

2) Declare the array in `main()` and pass it to the two function.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Channeling in C had mentioned by Jerry Cain in [Stanford CS107 - Programming Paradigms](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107).

The output is starting from 0 and then going till 99 on my machine(macBook), you can print the address of the array.

I think that the address of array to print is less than the first array.
That's why the output the first two number is random number.